# Looking for a word that describes this emotion: I'm amused, but ashamed to be amused at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: you laugh at someone getting hurt on America's Funniest Home videos, and then are ashamed that you laughed at their pain. Or you want to laugh at an off-color joke, but are ashamed that you found it funny in the first place. Or someone tells you a story about a personal misfortune, and you find it funny, but you are trying not to laugh and are disappointed with yourself for finding it funny.

Sample: I was [word] when my boyfriend caught his privates in the zipper of his jeans.

Anyone?

Comment: Not the single-word answer you're looking for, but a common way of expressing this emotion in AmE is, "I'm going to hell for laughing at this."

Comment: "Embarrassed amusement" is a phrase I might use.  (And, BTW, that can be incredibly painful.)

Answer (score 3):

[Schadenfreude](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/schadenfreude) fits most of your examples. The fact that English had to borrow a German term to cover this would seem to indicate that there is no native word that covers your actual answer.

Comment: Or it might indicate that Germans are more likely to derive pleasure from someone else's pain...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like *chagrinned*. *American Heritage* defines *[chagrin](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chagrin)* as

> A keen feeling of mental unease, as of annoyance or embarrassment, caused by failure, disappointment, or a disconcerting event: To her chagrin, the party ended just as she arrived.

While it is not limited to embarrassment associated with amusement, it might suit.

There is also the concept of *[guilty pleasure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guilty-pleasure)*

> Something, such as a movie, television program, or piece of music, that one enjoys despite feeling that it is not generally held in high regard

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

The idea is *I like it but I shouldn't* is a good bit broader, but it aligns with highbrow types giggling at lowbrow culture.

Comment: I was thinking *abashed*, a synonym of *chagrinned*.   I think the connotations are slightly better.

Comment: @stevesliva A good one. Add it as an answer. It gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I was **surreptitiously laughing** when my boyfriend caught his privates in the zipper of his jeans.

*When someone behaves in a surreptitious way, they're being secretive. They're doing something that they don't want to be seen doing (i.e. in a stealthy way)*.

Comment: Secretive and stealthy, yes, but it does not have the component of shame that OP is specifically asking for.  Also is not a single word, which is requested by OP's tag.

Comment: @HollyK - Good remark, even if a hidden smile suggests the feeling  of shame. To be more explicit, **shamefully** may fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a single word as you requested, OP, but I'm not certain that there is a single word in English that expresses the sentiment you are looking for.

The closest I can come is **guiltily amused**.

You are amused, but feel guilty for being so.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the name of an emotion, per se, but you could sum up your feelings using a facial expression can expresses part humor part embarrassment:

> I was **half-smiling** when my boyfriend caught his privates in the zipper
> of his jeans.

**half-smile** (n.)

> a smile that is uncertain or short-lived [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/half-smile)

---

> When Yusuf then says, "My father has bloomed?" their misunderstanding
> becomes clear. What do Yusuf's comment and sarcastic chuckle and
> Ayla's subsequent embarrassed **half-smile** mean? [A. Kotaman et al.;
> *Neo-Islamic Culture's Influence on Recent Turkish Media*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Neo_Islamic_Culture_s_Influence_on_Recen/CvlVDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=chuckled%20with%20an%20embarrassed%20half-smile&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)

> Zack was taller than May by a head; she looked up at him, delighted.
> There was an embarrassed **half smile** on his face, but he didn't
> look displeased. [Holly LeCraw; *The Half Brother*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Half_Brother/qoJaBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=embarrassed%20half-smile&pg=PT120&printsec=frontcover)

> He laughs then, a false laugh, an embarrassing laugh, embarrassing to
> all of us. No one says anything. I kind of **half-smile** to show I
> know it is a joke, but a joke I obviously don't condone [Cate Sweeney;
> *Selfish Jean*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Selfish_Jean/oqbG0us6lMYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=half-smile%20laugh%20embarrass&pg=PT9&printsec=frontcover)